# Jira - JQL for disclosed tickets after 5 days of moving in "Done" column

Tags: jira, jql

I have found one of query meant to what I am looking for,

```
project = SR AND issuetype = Bug AND status in (Backlog, "In Progress", "In Progress") ORDER BY created ASC
```

I want those all tickets to be in board except tickets those are in "Done". I am looking for JQL to set Tickets which are resolved and moved in "Done" should disappear after 5 days.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. I think you want to see all bugs, but tickets which have been resolved should not be displayed after five days. Then this JQL is more or less what you need:

```
project = SR AND issuetype = Bug 
AND (resolution = Unresolved OR resolved >= -5d)
ORDER BY created ASC
```

Comment: You understand correct. Can you please clarify for resolved status. As of now it I applying on my project, its working differently with minor update in query resolution != Done .  I need to update resolved >= 10 days and more.

Comment: Be aware that a resolution can have other values than "Done", such as "Duplicate" and "Cannot Reproduce" (in fact possible resolutions are configurable, so might be different in your environment).

Comment: But that is probably not what you want to know. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Finally this is worked : Project = SR AND issuetype = Bug AND (status != Done OR resolved >= -5d) ORDER BY created ASC